# Generate a JSON structure from a file based on the number of columns in the file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I have a problem where I need to generate a json payload for passing it as data to an api, the problem is that I need to generate the json structure based on the number of IDs that are coming from the file. 
Eg: if there are 5 IDs for an individual then I need to generate 5 rows of data; if there are 4 IDs then 4 rows and so on...

This is how my data file looks like:

```
Member_ID,User_ID,Proxy_ID,A_ID,Login_ID,First_Name,Last_Name
M1000,U1000,P1000,A1000,Jim1,Jim,Kong
M2000,U2000,P2000,A2000,OlilaJ,Olila,Jayavarman
M3000,U3000,P3000,A3000,LisaKop,Lisa,Kopkingg
M4000,U4000,P4000,A4000,KishoreP,Kishore,Pindhar
M5000,U5000,P5000,A5000,Gobi123,Gobi,Nadar
```

Data can also look like:

```
Member_ID,User_ID,A_ID,Login_ID,First_Name,Last_Name
M1000,U1000,A1000,Jim1,Jim,Kong
M2000,U2000,A2000,OlilaJ,Olila,Jayavarman
M3000,U3000,A3000,LisaKop,Lisa,Kopkingg
M4000,U4000,A4000,KishoreP,Kishore,Pindhar
M5000,U5000,A5000,Gobi123,Gobi,Nadar
```

I am unable to figure out a way to dynamically generate the number of lines for each such kind of input file.

```
from datetime import datetime
import json
import requests

start_time = datetime.now()

delim = "," # Just in case we switch to tsv or something
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

with open('Documents/Onboarding_sample.csv', 'r') as file:
    i = next(file)
    listcolumns = i.split(",")
    sub = "ID"
    IDcolumns = [s for s in listcolumns if sub.lower() in s.lower()]
    print len(IDcolumns)
    for line in file:
        line_list = line.split(delim)
        Member_ID = line_list[0]
        User_ID = line_list[1]
        Proxy_ID = line_list[2]
        A_ID = line_list[3]
        payload = { 
            "IndividualInfo":
            [{
            "Member_ID": Member_ID,
            "Identifiertype":"001",
            "EType:01"
            }
            {
            "User_ID": User_ID,
            "Identifiertype":"001",
            "EType:01"
            }
            {
            "Proxy_ID": Proxy_ID,
            "Identifiertype":"001",
            "EType:01"
            }
            {
            "A_ID": A_ID,
            "Identifiertype":"001",
            "EType:01"
            }
            ]
        }
        try:
            r = requests.post("http://www.google.com/blahblah", data=json.dumps(payload), timeout=(1,20), headers=headers)
            r.raise_for_status()
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
            print "HTTP Error:%s" %errh
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
            print "Error Connecting:%s" %errc
        except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
            print "Timeout error:%s" %errt

        print "This is a JSON object."
        print payload

end_time = datetime.now()

print('Duration: {}'.format(end_time - start_time))
```

Can someone please let me know how to do it correctly and dynamically irrespective of what ID I am getting in the file.

Comment: note you have invalide data, pobably misisng quotation in
            "Identifiertype:001", and some comas

Comment: Your payload is neither a valid python syntax nor a valid json structure.  What is your expected json output?

Comment: I changed it to include the commas, does it look fine now?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  Have you ran this code? It would definitely give you a `SyntaxError`.  You're still missing the commas between the nested `dict`s, and the key/value pair within the nested `dict`s are all messed up as well.  Is `"Identifiertype:001"` supposed to be `{"Identifiertype":"001"}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by others, it's probably easier to use the `csv` module, but it's achievable with the convention method as well:

```
delim = "," # Just in case we switch to tsv or something

with open('test.txt', 'r') as file:
    # Create a list of valid headers in comma seperated values and their respective index
    header = [(i, col) for i, col in enumerate(next(file).rstrip().split(delim)) if col.endswith('_ID')]

    # Create a list of data in comma seperated values
    data = [l.rstrip().split(delim) for l in file.readlines()]

    # Go through each record to create a payload
    for record in data:

        # Here we use the header index to retrieve the respective data to create the dictionary with list comprehension
        payload = {'IndividualInfo': [{key: record[i], 'Identifiertype': '001', 'EType':'01'} for i, key in header]}

        # Do whatever you need with json.dumps(payload)
```

The results are as such:

```
# the index/header pairs
# [(0, 'Member_ID'), (1, 'User_ID'), (2, 'Proxy_ID'), (3, 'A_ID'), (4, 'Login_ID')]

# the separated data
# [['M1000', 'U1000', 'P1000', 'A1000', 'Jim1', 'Jim', 'Kong'], ['M2000', 'U2000', 'P2000', 'A2000', 'OlilaJ', 'Olila', 'Jayavarman'], ['M3000', 'U3000', 'P3000', 'A3000', 'LisaKop', 'Lisa', 'Kopkingg'], ['M4000', 'U4000', 'P4000', 'A4000', 'KishoreP', 'Kishore', 'Pindhar'], ['M5000', 'U5000', 'P5000', 'A5000', 'Gobi123', 'Gobi', 'Nadar']]

# The payloads
# {'IndividualInfo': [{'Member_ID': 'M1000', 'Identifiertype': '001', 'EType': '01'}, {'User_ID': 'U1000', 'Identifiertype': '001', 'EType': '01'}, {'Proxy_ID': 'P1000', 'Identifiertype': '001', 'EType': '01'}, {'A_ID': 'A1000', 'Identifiertype': '001', 'EType': '01'}, {'Login_ID': 'Jim1', 'Identifiertype': '001', 'EType': '01'}]}
# {'IndividualInfo': [{'Member_ID': 'M2000', 'Identifiertype': '001', 'EType': '01'}, {'User_ID': 'U2000', 'Identifiertype': '001', 'EType': '01'}, {'Proxy_ID': 'P2000', 'Identifiertype': '001', 'EType': '01'}, {'A_ID': 'A2000', 'Identifiertype': '001', 'EType': '01'}, {'Login_ID': 'OlilaJ', 'Identifiertype': '001', 'EType': '01'}]}
# {'IndividualInfo': [{'Member_ID': 'M3000', 'Identifiertype': '001', 'EType': '01'}, {'User_ID': 'U3000', 'Identifiertype': '001', 'EType': '01'}, {'Proxy_ID': 'P3000', 'Identifiertype': '001', 'EType': '01'}, {'A_ID': 'A3000', 'Identifiertype': '001', 'EType': '01'}, {'Login_ID': 'LisaKop', 'Identifiertype': '001', 'EType': '01'}]}
# {'IndividualInfo': [{'Member_ID': 'M4000', 'Identifiertype': '001', 'EType': '01'}, {'User_ID': 'U4000', 'Identifiertype': '001', 'EType': '01'}, {'Proxy_ID': 'P4000', 'Identifiertype': '001', 'EType': '01'}, {'A_ID': 'A4000', 'Identifiertype': '001', 'EType': '01'}, {'Login_ID': 'KishoreP', 'Identifiertype': '001', 'EType': '01'}]}
# {'IndividualInfo': [{'Member_ID': 'M5000', 'Identifiertype': '001', 'EType': '01'}, {'User_ID': 'U5000', 'Identifiertype': '001', 'EType': '01'}, {'Proxy_ID': 'P5000', 'Identifiertype': '001', 'EType': '01'}, {'A_ID': 'A5000', 'Identifiertype': '001', 'EType': '01'}, {'Login_ID': 'Gobi123', 'Identifiertype': '001', 'EType': '01'}]}
```

Note I used `enumerate()` to create the index/header combo as it gives you an accurate method to locate the respective data if there were other columns in between the `_ID` columns.

## Edit:

For Python 2.7, use the following instead ([sample on repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/EvilSvelteKnowledge)):

```
delim = "," # Just in case we switch to tsv or something

with open('test.txt', 'r') as file:
    # Create a list of valid headers in comma seperated values and their respective index
    header = [(i, col) for i, col in enumerate(next(file).rstrip().split(delim)) if col.endswith('_ID')]
    # Create a list of data in comma seperated values
    data = []
    for f in file:
        data.append(f.rstrip().split(delim))

# We're done with reading the file,
# We can proceed outside the `with` context manager from this point

# Go through each record to create a payload
for record in data:

    # Here we use the header index to retrieve the respective data to create the dictionary with list comprehension
    payload = {'IndividualInfo': [{key: record[i], 'Identifiertype': '001', 'EType':'01'} for i, key in header]}

    # Do whatever you need with json.dumps(payload)
```

Comment: I am trying to run this, but it gives me an error,
    ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data

Comment: Runs fine on my Python 3.7.  What version are you on?

Comment: Oh! I am on 2.7

Comment: Yikes.  If you're not limited I'd suggest moving up to version 3 if possible.  Either way, I've updated the answer.  It's been tested in repl.it so it should be fine now.

Comment: This works great! Thank you so much :)

Also, if I wanted to pool the processes so even bigger files with more than a million records would work faster, how can we do that?

Comment: Regarding performance I'm not too sure.  I think unless you're limited in memory the code should still run fine speed-wise. But if you're processing several gigabytes of data perhaps extract the payload within the file stream and post it right away.  i.e. instead of doing `data.append...` just do `record = f.rstrip().split(delim)` and move the `payload` line right after it.

Answer (score 0):

```
delim = "," # Just in case we switch to tsv or something
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

with open('Documents/Onboarding_sample.csv', 'r') as file:
    i = next(file)
    listcolumns = i.split(delim)
    sub = "ID"
    payload = {"IndividualInfo": []}
    for line in file:
        line_list = line.split(delim)  

        for val in enumerate(i, line_list)
            if val.lower().endswith(SUB.lower()):                   
                payload["individualInfo"].append(
                     {
                        header: val,
                        "Identifiertype": "001",
                        "EType":"01"
                      }
                )

        try:
            r = requests.post("http://www.google.com/blahblah", data=json.dumps(payload), timeout=(1,20), headers=headers)
            r.raise_for_status()
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
            print "HTTP Error:%s" %errh
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
            print "Error Connecting:%s" %errc
        except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
            print "Timeout error:%s" %errt

        print "This is a JSON object."
        print payload
```

The above solution is not ideal, proably best to combine with csv dict reader as suggested in other answer, then filter out ids

```
import csv
with open('names.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    print reader.fieldnames # gets you file header
    for row in reader:
        for k in row:
            if k.lower().endswith('id'):
                  ....
```

Comment: construct the entire payload for each and every "else" clause?

Comment: actually I did not undestood intinally that all the id treated similiarly. A simple if suffices. The above solution is not ideal, proably best to combine with csv as suggested in other answer, then filter out ids

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` and `.to_json(orient='records')`

```
df = pd.read_csv(open(file))
df.to_json(orient='records')
```

This will output as many records as ID's in the file:

```
[{"Member_ID":"M1000","User_ID":"U1000","A_ID":"A1000","Login_ID":"Jim1","First_Name":"Jim","Last_Name":"Kong"},...,{"Member_ID":"M2000","User_ID":"U2000","A_ID":"A2000","Login_ID":"OlilaJ","First_Name":"Olila","Last_Name":"Jayavarman"}]
```

Comment: This approach will output as many records as ID's in the file.

Comment: Nope, it does not do that!

Comment: I see now, and if there are multiple users there would be multiple Individual Infos in a list?

Answer (score 0):

Use DictReader to get the headers in the file

```
import csv
with open('names.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    print reader.fieldnames # gets you file header
    for row in reader:
        Member_ID = row["Member_ID"]
        User_ID = row["User_ID"]
        Proxy_ID = row.get("Proxy_ID", "")
        A_ID = row.get("A_ID", "")

        if Proxy_ID:
            ....
        else:
            ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do:

```
...
with open('Documents/Onboarding_sample.csv') as f:
    rows = [line.strip().split(',') for line in f.readlines()]

payload = [{key: val for key, val in zip(rows[0], row) if key.endswith('_ID')}
           for row in rows[1:]]
...
```

or

```
import csv

...
with open('Documents/Onboarding_sample.csv') as f:
    rows = [row for row in csv.reader(f)]

payload = [{key: val for key, val in zip(rows[0], row) if key.endswith('_ID')}
           for row in rows[1:]]
...
```

Comment: No, this is not something that I want. The output from your logic is 1 JSON for each line in the file.